# Changing the price text in b2bking plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

The b2bking plugin has helped me alot with my shop. One of its features in that it can display both a wholesale and a retail price.

My problem is that we are a swedish shop and I would like it to say "ÅF-pris" and "RRP" instead of what is outputs by default.

I've tried modifying the code inside the plugin. It works but I know that it will stop working as soon as I update the plugin. This is why I want to do it with filter hooks provided by the plugin.

What I've tried (I am kinda new to PHP)

```
add_filter('b2bking_filter_wholesale_price_final', 'alex_translate_price_text');

function alex_translate_price_text($text_retail_price, $text_final_price){
    $text_retail_price = 'test_RRP: ';
    return $text_retail_price;

    $text_final_price = 'test_åf-pris: ';
    return $text_final_price;
}
```

in the plugin, hook looks like this:

```
$price = apply_filters('b2bking_filter_wholesale_price_final', $price, $text_retail_price, $retail_price, $text_final_price, $b2b_price_price, $product_id);
```

My thought process is that I want to change the variables "$text_retail_price" and "$text_final_price" to "ÅF-pris" and "RRP" as right now they contain "Retail price" and "Wholesale price".

Comment: contact the dev unless u source it illegally :D

Comment: Oh, its illegal to ask for help about this one line of code?

Answer (score 0):

We're the developers of the plugin, glad to hear it's been useful to you,

There's now a setting where you can change these directly via B2BKing -> Settings -> Language & Text.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Great plugin and amazing support :)